# Gif image is not displaying in android

Tags: android, animation, gif

In my android application i need to show gif image, i have referred some code to display but its not working dont know where i have missed, check it out my code

MY Class
    public class SampleAnimgif extends View {

```
    private Movie mMovie;
    private long mMovieStart;

    public SampleAnimgif(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.siren);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    public SampleAnimgif(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.siren);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    public SampleAnimgif(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrSet, defStyle);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.siren);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0x00000000);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) { // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        if (mMovie != null) {
            int dur = mMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }
            int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() / 2 - mMovie.width() / 2,
                    getHeight() / 2 - mMovie.height() / 2);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

My xml class

```
 <com.example.activities.SampleAnimgif
            android:id="@+id/gif_view"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Suggestion are most welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late answer for this question, but it might help others. I had the same problem as users and I couldn't solve it. After lots of Googling, i found the solution. The problem is the hardware acceleration is enabled in the mobile for android above 4.0(I'm not sure. It might be above 3.0). What all you need to do is make hardwareaccelation as false while declaring activity.

```
<activity
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
```